# Trigger cache clearing on table crud operation in linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a method that gets all the records from a particular database, then stores it in the cache.  The next time that method is called, it first checks the cache to see if it can simply return a cache version, if that cache object hasn't been expired.

**Question**: how do I trigger a method everytime dataContext.SubmitChanges() is called?  For example, if I get all the books from the Book table and store it in Cache["AllBooks"], I want this cache object to be cleared on any crud operations related to the Book table.

**What I'm currently doing**:

```
var b = dataContext.Books.Where(x => x.BookId == 4).SingleOrDefault();
b.Title = "new title for book w/ id of 4";
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
ClearBookCache();
```

later...

```
private void ClearBookCache() {
    CustomCachingSystem.Clear["AllBooks"];
}
```

**What I want**: the ClearBookCache() to be automatically triggered on any Book table crud operations, vs. me having to remember to call it everytime I do a crud operation on the Book table.

**Note**: I wouldn't want that ClearBookCache() method to be called if I do a crud operation on a table that's unrelated to the Book table.

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: All CRUD operations? More like CUD - without the read part, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [SqlDependency Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx). Basically, it will let you detect changes to the queried data (if you use M$ SQL Server 2005+).

You may want to look into [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166043%28SQL.90%29.aspx) technology (if you use M$ SQL Server 2005+).

Detecting it directly in your application probably won't be enough - you won't be able to detect any changes that were performed outside of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DataContext.GetChangeSet()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx) - you could inherit from DataContext and override the SubmitChanges methods to clear the relevant caches based on the ChangeSet contents and then call MyBase.SubmitChanges(...).

Comment: However, Jaroslav's comment is of course very valid - this won't pick up on any changes made by e.g. triggers, not will you be 'doing the right thing' with the cache if other users are modifying data you have cached.